# SNS: How to create platform application for APNS voip?

Tags: c#, apple-push-notifications, voip, amazon-sns

I'm trying to create a platform application for APNS programmatically to do voip push notifications. I'm using a voip certificate and doing like this:

```
var attributes = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "PlatformCredential", password },
                { "PlatformPrincipal", $"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n{ apnsCertificate }\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----" }
            };

var request = new CreatePlatformApplicationRequest { Attributes = attributes, Name = "ApnsPlatform", Platform = "APNS" };
var response = _amazonSnsClient.CreatePlatformApplication(request);
```

However, I get this error saying I can't use a VoIP certificate for an application iOS Production:

```
Amazon.SimpleNotificationService.Model.InvalidParameterException: Invalid parameter: Attributes Reason: You provided a certificate of type VoIP, which cannot be used to create an application of type iOS Production. Please select an application of type VoIP or provide a certificate of type iOS Production
```

So, I've been thinking I need to set the "Platform" property in the above method to something like like "APNS_VOIP"/"VOIP"/"VoIP" (I tried a few), but the SNS documentation only specifies APNS and APNS_SANDBOX. I have a feeling I'm missing something obvious here but searched so much without finding anything.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out setting "Platform = APNS_VOIP" is the right approach! Having tried so many things I guess I got tired and missed the error messages differing.

If entering an invalid platform type the error says it's invalid or unknown, but for APNS_VOIP it instead said something's wrong with the credentials. In my case I hadn't understood that also the password in the above "PlatformCredential" property needs to be enclosed by BEGIN/END keywords, however here it's 'RSA PRIVATE KEY' instead, like this:

```
{ "PlatformCredential", $"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n{ password }\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" }
```

I could then create a platform application for VoIP.